# Difference between angular.merge and angular.extend?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can some one please explain me the difference between angular.merge and angular.extend..And what does deep copy means and when should it be used ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Extend : to shallow copy the properties of the source objects from right to left, all the way to the destination object.

Example: extend person and job objects and vise versa.

```
       //------------------------------------Extend--------------------------

        $scope.extendPersonToJob = function () {
           var person = { 'Name': 'Monica', 'Age': '25', 'Skills': { 'name': 'travelling', 'place': 'Queenstown' } };
            var job = { 'Title': 'Programmer', 'Experience': '5',   'Skills': { 'name': 'Designing', 'experience': '2', 'certified': 'true' } };
            // extend from Person to Job

            $scope.personTojob = angular.extend(person, job);
             // output : { 'Name': 'Monica', 'Age': '25', 'Skills': { 'name': 'Designing', 'experience': '2', 'certified': 'true' } , 'Title': 'Programmer', 'Experience': '5'}             
        }

        $scope.extendJobToPerson = function () {
            var person = { 'Name': 'Monica', 'Age': '25', 'Skills': { 'name': 'travelling', 'place': 'Queenstown' } };
            var job = { 'Title': 'Programmer', 'Experience': '5', 'Skills': { 'name': 'Designing', 'experience': '2', 'certified': 'true' } };

            // extend from job to person
            $scope.jobToperson = angular.extend(job, person)
           // output : { 'Name': 'Monica', 'Age': '25', 'Skills': { 'name': 'travelling' , 'place': 'Queenstown' }  , 'Title': 'Programmer', 'Experience': '5'}             

        }
```

Merge is to deep (recursively) copy the properties of the source objects to the destination object.

Example: merge person and job objects and vise versa.

```
    //------------------------------------Merge------------------------------
        $scope.mergePersonToJob = function () {

            var person = { 'Name': 'Monica', 'Age': '25', 'Skills': { 'name': 'travelling', 'place': 'Queenstown' } };
            var job = { 'Title': 'Programmer', 'Experience': '5', 'Skills': { 'name': 'Designing', 'experience': '2', 'certified': 'true' } };
            // merge from Person to Job

            $scope.personTojob = angular.merge(person, job);

            // output :  { 'Name': 'Monica', 'Age': '25', 'Skills': { 'name': 'Designing', 'experience': '2', 'certified': 'true', 'place': 'Queenstown' }, 'Title': 'Programmer', 'Experience': '5' };
        }

        $scope.mergeJobToPerson = function () {
            var person = { 'Name': 'Monica', 'Age': '25', 'Skills': { 'name': 'travelling', 'place': 'Queenstown' } };
            var job = { 'Title': 'Programmer', 'Experience': '5', 'Skills': { 'name': 'Designing', 'experience': '2', 'certified': 'true' } };

            // merge from job to person
            $scope.jobToperson = angular.merge(job, person)

            // output : { 'Name': 'Monica', 'Age': '25', 'Skills': { 'name': 'travelling', 'experience': '2', 'certified': 'true', 'place': 'Queenstown' }, 'Title': 'Programmer', 'Experience': '5' };
        }
```

have a look this [Example](https://codepen.io/UserIsMonica/pen/XjjmEP) and compare for better understanding. please correct me if wrong.

PC : [David Cai's Blog](http://davidcai.github.io/blog/posts/copy-vs-extend-vs-merge/)

Comment: @Shijil Narayan i tried to explain deep (recursive) copy  and shallow copy using Merge and extend with person and job objects example.

Comment: Thanks a lot Monica.The example you gave made things more clear.

Comment: @ShijilNarayan i am glad to help you. but i just came to know that my codepen example  link was n't saved and showing default angular js page. i applologies for that. but i just have updated it have a look.

Comment: Yes ,but David Cai's blog link u shared helped me in understanding it more clearly.Will go through your codepen example too.Anyway Thank you

Answer (score 2):

From [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge#overview).

> Unlike extend(), merge() recursively descends into object properties
> of source objects, performing a deep copy.

Comment: Thanks Levi but still what does deep copy mean ?

Comment: @ShijilNarayan if you have nested objects, merge() will copy them as well, but using extend() doesn't.

Comment: Thanks Levi for the help